# Windows 10 Taskbar/Startmenu/Notifications not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, start-menu

- **Symptoms (Windows 10):**

  - Startmenu & Notification area won't open
  - Right click on any of the icons in my taskbar doesn't do anything
  - Many Windows apps don't work
  - The "Loading" cursor flashes like crazy from time to time (especially when trying to interact with the taskbar)
  - Adding a different user account seems impossible:

    - CMD: adding a user works fine, however I cannot log into the account
    - UI: adding a new user doesn't work at all. A window opens and closes again.
  - The Microsoft Taskbar troubleshooter detects the following problem, however seems to be unable to fix it (even when run as
    administrator):

> "Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost" and "Microsoft.Windows.Cortana" applications need to be installed correctly.

- **I have already tried:**

  - Adding a new user account
  - Some user (who had the exact same problems) fixed it by setting a
    different default monitor, however I don't have a second monitor and
    I never had one, so this should not be the cause
  - Deleting C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/TileDataLayer
  - Repairing windows

    - running `sfc /scannow`
    - running `dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth`
    - running `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`
    - reparing the system via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> -> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + Restart -> repair didn't work either.
    - this ps script:

> Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}<
>
> Get-appxpackage -all *shellexperience* -packagetype bundle |% {add-appxpackage -register -disabledevelopmentmode ($_.installlocation + “\appxmetadata\appxbundlemanifest.xml”)}
>
> Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
>
> Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Windows.Cortana | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}

If you have any idea how to fix this, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweaking.com has a nice program called "Windows Repair" (http://www.tweaking.com/files/setups/tweaking.com_windows_repair_aio_setup.exe), which was able to solve the issue for me. I still don't know, what caused it.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.